# In-App Billing Library Can't find in the sdk Manager

Tags: android, sdk

I am trying to develop an app with In-App Billing. According to the documentation , First I need to download the In-App Billing library using the sdk manager . But I cant find this library in the extras folder. I also noticed that some other librarys also missing from the extras folder. I have checked the sdk/extras/google  folder and there is only one folder named usb_driver.

Here is the screenshot of the sdk manager.
[image]

Any help is appreciated..

Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Issue Solved!!.

1. Install the latest Android sdk tools using sdk manager
2. Click help - > check for updates in eclipse
3. open the sdk manager again

Now shows all the packages...